What's the rational behind encoding a single input as a distribution over the latent space in VAE?
I've been reading some tutorials on VAE, but find myself struggling with the idea that a single input is represented as a distribution in the latent space.
Normally, as in vanilla autoencoder, a single input is mapped into a single point in latent space, and this obviously makes sense. In VAE, however, a single input is mapped into a parametric Gaussian distribution. Does it mean any sample from this distribution should give me the same output? What's the rationale behind this practice? How exactly does it help to form a regularized latent space?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
